# no video with supported format and MIME type found in django

Tags: python, django

no video with supported format and MIME type found

A huge screen for video is displayed and says the message above. How do I solve this? This happens to me only in Mozilla Firefox and not on Google Chrome. I am using webm videos and mp4 videos.
I'm Uploading a video from the admin panel

model.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='video')
```

view.py

```
from .models import Video

def home(request):
    video = Video.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'video/index.html', {'videos':video})
```

url.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

home.html

```
 {% for video in videos %}
     <video width="320" height="240" controls>
     <source src="{{video.video.url}}" type="video/webm">
     </video> 
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your `home.html` is always saying `video/webm`.  If some of them are MPEG4, it needs to say that.

Comment: I don't understand....

Comment: Your `home.html` has `type="video/webm"`.  Will they always be `video/webm`?